# O que é MUSL? Quais os prós de alguém estar portando ele para o meu portátil?

Tags: c, linux, musl

Estou interessado no prós que isso pode trazer pro meu portátil.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A **musl** (cujo nome é grafado em minúsculas na página oficial) é uma [Biblioteca padrão do C](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblioteca_padr%C3%A3o_do_C). De acordo com seu autor, tem o objetivo de ser uma *libc* limpa, padrão e eficiente.

Seu OS alvo é o `Linux 2.6`, e está disponível oficialmente nas plataformas `i386`, `x86_64`, `arm`, `mips`, `microblaze` e `powerpc`. Tem suporte experimental para outras arquiteturas, listadas no site oficial.

Uma das vantagens do seu uso em *mobile* é seu tamanho e capacidade de concorrência. Outro ponto muito importante para desenvolvedores de aplicações comerciais é o fato dela usar a **licença MIT**, em geral mais permissiva do que a da *glibc* que é **LGPL**, em especial, permitindo seu uso em aplicações fechadas também.

Veja um breve comparativo com a **glibc**:

```
COMPARAÇÃO DE TAMANHO                musl            glibc
----------------------------------   -------------   -----------------
Coleção de bibliotecas estáticas   | 426k          | 2.0M
Coleção de bibliotecas dinâmicas   | 527k          | 7.9M
Menor executável C                 | 1.8k          | 662k
“hello” estático (com printf)      | 13k           | 662k

COMPORTAMENTO EM EXAUSTÃO            musl            glibc
----------------------------------   -------------   -----------------
Armazenamento Thread-local         | reporta falha | aborta
SIGEV_THREAD timers                | não falha     | perda de overruns
pthread_cancel                     | não falha     | aborta
regcomp e regexec                  | reporta falha | quebra
fnmatch                            | não falha     | reporta falha
Família printf                     | não falha     | reporta falha
Família strtol                     | não falha     | não falha

COMPARAÇÃO DE RECURSOS               musl            glibc
----------------------------------   -------------   -----------------
API de threads C11                 | sim           | não
agendamento de processos POSIX     | apenas stub   | incorreto
Localedef POSIX                    | não           | sim
páginas de código 8 bits legadas   | não           | lento, via gconv
Páginas de código CJK legadas      | não           | lento, via gconv
UTF-8 multibyte                    | nativo;       | lento, via gconv;
                                   | 100% conforme | não conforme
Conversão de caracteres Iconv      | a maior parte | o básico
                                   | dos encodings |
extensão de transliteração Iconv   | não           | sim
Openwall-style TCB shadow          | sim           | não
Sun RPC, NIS                       | não           | sim
Profiling Gmon                     | não           | sim
recursos de debug                  | não           | sim
```

<sup><sub>(veja o link para a tabela original no final da resposta)</sub></sup>

De acordo com a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl) <sup>en</sup>, a **musl** foi escrita do zero, para permitir "linkagem" estática com robustez para aplicações realtime, evitando condições de corrida e exaustão de recursos presentes nas implementações mais comuns até então.

O *runtime* é um arquivo único, com interface binária estável, permitindo *deploy* com a aplicação principal num executável único sem inchar seu tamanho final.

O projeto alega ser compatível com POSIX 2008 e o padrão C11. Em 2015 era a biblioteca C padrão das distros Alpine Linux, Dragora 3, OpenWRT, Sabotage, Morpheus Linux e uma opção no Void Linux.

Página oficial:

> https://www.musl-libc.org/

Aqui temos um comparativo completo com outras *libc*, de onde foi extraída a tabela acima:

> http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html

Comment: Ficou muito mais claro, obrigado por responder.